# Itemise within a caption doesn't work

Tags: captions, itemize

I've been trying to figure this out, but while I did find another thread with the same problem, I didn't understand what they specifically did to solve it. So I'm using the package

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

And want to have the following figure with a caption:

```
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.47]{HP.png}
 \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
 \caption{
  text1:

  \begin{itemize}
   \renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
   \item blue: $0.1 - 0.36$
   \item green: $0.36 - 0.98$
   \item red: $0.98 - 3.5$
   \item purple: $3.5 +$
  \end{itemize}

  text2 }
 \label{HP}
\end{figure}
```

And it gives me this error:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
```

The other solution did something, but I couldn't figure out what, since they were using "foo" "bar" instead of real commands.

UPDATE: with the proposed solution below

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{HP.png}
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
  \caption[]{text1:

    \begin{itemize}[label={--}]
      \item blue: 0.1 -- 0.36
      \item green: 0.36 -- 0.98
      \item red: 0.98 -- 3.5
      \item purple: 3.5 +
    \end{itemize}

    text2}
\end{figure}
```

I now get error `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`

Can anyone else try it and see if they get the same error?

Comment: Did you add `\usepackage{enumitem}`?

Comment: Yes `\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}`

Answer (score 8):

Note that the caption is a floating argument, and they are fragile. With `singlelinecheck=off` there is some safety, but you should supply a non-paragraph caption as the floating argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,graphicx,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
  \caption[]{text1:

    \begin{itemize}[label={--}]
      \item blue: 0.1 -- 0.36
      \item green: 0.36 -- 0.98
      \item red: 0.98 -- 3.5
      \item purple: 3.5 +
    \end{itemize}

    text2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of the optional argument that doesn't contain any paragraphs. It's currently blank, which doesn't matter if you're not using `\listoffigures`.

Comment: I tried copypasting your solution, and adding the enumitem package, but now it gives the error `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon: What `\documentclass` are you using, since I can't replicate your issue. My minimal example works without problem. Can you provide a minimal example that replicates your issue like I did?

Comment: Ok, the document class is `\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}` so could that be it? Would using that reproduce the error for you?

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon: Okay; [`mnas`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnas) is not supported by [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption). So, I suggest using [this code](http://pastebin.com/VMRFvmd5) which uses ``\\`` to denote line-breaks and simulate an `itemize` list. Using an alternative LoF caption is still suggested, as an itemized construction for the LoF would look weird. Here's [the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gDeu.png).

Comment: It doesn't seem that the caption allows even `\\`, it gives me a similar error `! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.` So I guess there's no way around it in the mnras package.

Answer (score 2):

**If your list offend you, cut it off**

A simple and safe solution is move out after `\caption{}` the itemize list and the remaining text.

It could be some problem with this approach if some class/package/macro control the caption position (i.e., you put the caption after the image, but the caption will will printed in a top position), or change the font, or set some vertical skip after the caption (`\belowcaptionskip`), but otherwise ... Why not?

**Do not underestimate the power of the `minipages`**

Often, people search for complex solutions that can be solved with a simple bounding box. With respect to the caption, a itemize list inside a `minipage` is only one unbreakable box. This allow to circumvent the caption restrictions like avoid paragraph breaks.

Some examples:

[image: mwe]]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}\par
  \caption[Text1]{Some short text 1:}
      \leftmargini.4\linewidth
       \begin{itemize}
          \renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
          \itemsep0pt\parskip0pt
          \item blue: 0.1 -- 0.36
          \item green: 0.36 -- 0.98
          \item red: 0.98 -- 3.5
          \item purple: 3.5 +
       \end{itemize}
       Some short text 2.
\end{figure}
\hrule
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-b}
  \caption[Text1]{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
       Some short text 1:
       \leftmargini0pt
       \begin{itemize}
          \renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
          \itemsep0pt\parskip0pt
          \item blue: 0.1 -- 0.36
          \item green: 0.36 -- 0.98
          \item red: 0.98 -- 3.5
          \item purple: 3.5 +
       \end{itemize}
       Some short text 2.
    \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\hrule
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-c}
  \caption[Text1]{Some long text 1. Some long text 1.
    Some long text 1.Some long text 1: \parskip.5em\par
{\centering\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
\itemsep0pt\parskip0pt
      \item blue: 0.1 -- 0.36
      \item green: 0.36 -- 0.98
      \item red: 0.98 -- 3.5
      \item purple: 3.5 +
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\par}
Some long text 2. Some long text 2. Some long text 2. Some long text 2.}
\end{figure}
\hrule
\end{document}
```